# python + import C++ coding help. Missing compiler_cxx fix for MSVCCompiler; Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, mingw, scipy

I have scipy and numpy. So I installed `MinGW` as well as `Cygwin`. I added the path `o MinGW` to my
 environmental variables. But when I run my python code it shows this error message.

*No module named msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    Missing compiler_cxx fix for MSVCCompiler*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\jicrd_simulation.py", line 633, in <module>
    cProfile.run('run()','infoprof_c_old')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\cProfile.py", line 29, in run
    prof = prof.run(statement)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\cProfile.py", line 135, in run
    return self.runctx(cmd, dict, dict)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\cProfile.py", line 140, in runctx
    exec cmd in globals, locals
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\jicrd_simulation.py", line 615, in run
    P,trace=search(g)
  File "C:\Python27\jicrd_simulation.py", line 580, in search
    hits=compute_hits(g,pos,P)
  File "C:\Python27\jicrd_simulation.py", line 299, in compute_hits
    source_counts = thetarange(g,g.source,move)
  File "C:\Python27\jicrd_simulation.py", line 229, in thetarange
    headers=['<stdio.h>','<stdlib.h>','<math.h>','"'+g.path +'/comp.h"'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\weave\inline_tools.py", line 355, in inline
    **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\weave\inline_tools.py", line 482, in compile_function
      verbose=verbose, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\weave\ext_tools.py", line 367, in compile
      verbose = verbose, **kw)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\weave\build_tools.py", line 272, in build_extension
      setup(name = module_name, ext_modules = [ext],verbose=verb)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 186, in setup
      return old_setup(**new_attr)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setup
      raise SystemExit, "error: " + str(msg)
  CompileError: error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

So what should I do now? I have a MSVCCCompiler.

Comment: Just a guess, but since you're using Python2.7, it is probably looking for the specific MSVC compiler used to build Python 2.7, which IIRC is VS2008.

Answer (score 0):

As you're talking about C++ coding, I assume you want to compile a C/C++ extension. The way I got my C extensions to compile on Win**32** with MinGW was to explicitly append the compiler:

`python setup.py build_ext --compiler mingw32`

If you want to compile for Win**64**, MinGW seems not to be the best choice. I went with the tips [here](http://mattptr.net/2010/07/28/building-python-extensions-in-a-modern-windows-environment/) and [here](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2010-August/052408.html) and got my extensions to compile with VC++ 10 from the Microsoft SDK.